# numberForRowsInSection count from to

Tags: ios, arrays, tableview

I parse an array into my TableView via JSON but I only want to make my table view show the first 18 things in this array. The array consists 72 objects and gets refreshed every day.

The objects in this array are named "0" - "71"...that doesn't change just the items assigned to them change.

How do I make my array now show only the first 18 of it?

I tried this but no success.

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return self.arrayNeuheiten.count;

    if (arrayNeuheiten <= 17) {
        return self.arrayNeuheiten.count;
    } else if (arrayNeuheiten > 17 )
        return nil;
}
```

Would be great if anyone could help me with that!

Comment: Try returning 0 instead of nil
PS - Just an else will do.

Comment: The code after the first `return` will never run.

Comment: once check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return (self.arrayNeuheiten.count<17)?self.arrayNeuheiten.count :17;

}
```

Comment: I get a warning and an error. Warning: Ordered comparison between pointer and integer and error: Implicit conversion of 'int' to 'NSArray *' is disallowed in ARC.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
     return MIN(18, self.arrayNeuheiten.count);;
 }
```

Comment: if array count less than 17 at that time what will happend?.....while displaying the data in table app gets crashed array out of bound exception'l come

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
 {

        if(arrayNeuheiten.count >17)
        {
             NSRange r;
             r.location = 17;
             r.length = [someArray count]-17;
             [arrayNeuheiten removeObjectsInRange:r];
        }

            return self.arrayNeuheiten.count;

}
```